# Nginx not redirecting to my Tomcat app - what is wrong with this config file?

Tags: tomcat, nginx

My app is online at:
http://vps465.ns.planethoster.net:8090/rto/

I use port 8090 because 8080 is used by Glassfish on the same server.

The nginx config file says:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  realtimeopinion.com www.realtimeopinion.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:8090/rto/;
        #proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

Yet http://www.realtimeopinion.com redirects to a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on your real time opinion link from google chrome, with the debugger turned on shows that nginx is forwarding a 404 response that was generated by glassfish (which is on port 8080) not tomcat (which is 8090 and where you really want to go)

So I think that your config file is correct, except that the nginx that is running right now is working from a different config file, or perhaps an earlier version of the config file which previously specified port 8080.  In this second case, maybe you just need to restart nginx?

Comment: I restarted nginx, same result. Beside the config file for the app, is there a general config file of nginx I should look at?

Comment: Ok my mistake, I did not give a ".conf" extension to the config file.